# IIS 7.5 Caching Classic ASP Responses and Static Files

Tags: iis-7.5, cache, asp-classic

I have a really hard time migrating from Windows Server 2003 to Windows 2008 R2. My ASP code seems to work but after a while users start complaining they see other people's responses!

User 1: Search -> Get Record A (*) -> Edit -> Submit

User 2 (on another PC): Search -> Get Record A -> IE Shows the pre-edit version (*)!

I have disabled cache / kernel caching afterwards, but otherwise all settings should be default

On a somehow related issue: I have a .Net 2 ASP.NET application that logs using Log4net. After migrating to W2k8 R2 the log time stamps are well out of date. For example, at 5pm the last modified time still says 1AM (using both dir and explorer). Notepad shows the 5pm version. (I checked that if I edit a file and save it, the timestamp is correct)

I set up a virtual directory on IIS for the logs, and at 5pm I see content from 4pm. I tried forcing a refresh by appending a '?' to the end of the URL and it showed the 2pm version! I get old data even if I use another browser. Fiddler shows that the response time is current, and when I refresh the browser, which then uses the Modified-Since tag to look for post 5pm data, IIS would return that there is no change.

Pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Has someone been practicing voodoo near your server?

Comment: We have Sophos Endpoint Security (not sure if that's voodoo) which I may disable next. Problem is it's not reproducible ...